# SelectMany query with Where produces many SQL queries

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-6

I'm using for a GetAppRolesForUser function (and have tried variations of based on answers here):

```
private AuthContext db = new AuthContext();
...
var userRoles = Mapper.Map<List<RoleApi>>(
    db.Users.SingleOrDefault(u => u.InternetId == username)
      .Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Roles.Where(r => r.Asset.AssetName == application)));
```

I end up with this in SQL Profiler for every single RolesId each time:

```
exec sp_executesql N'SELECT 
    [Extent2].[GroupId] AS [GroupId], 
    [Extent2].[GroupName] AS [GroupName]
    FROM  [Auth].[Permissions] AS [Extent1]
    INNER JOIN [Auth].[Groups] AS [Extent2] ON [Extent1].[GroupId] = [Extent2].[GroupId]
    WHERE [Extent1].[RolesId] = @EntityKeyValue1',N'@EntityKeyValue1 int',@EntityKeyValue1=6786
```

How do I refactor so EF produces a single query for userRoles and doesn't take 18 seconds to run?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you're lazy loading the groups and roles.

One solution is eager load them before you call `SingleOrDefault`

```
var user = db.Users.Include(x => x.Groups.Select(y => y.Roles))
                   .SingleOrDefault(u => u.InternetId == username);

var groups = user.Groups.SelectMany(
                   g => g.Roles.Where(r => r.Asset.AssetName == application));

var userRoles = Mapper.Map<List<RoleApi>>(groups);
```

***Also note*** : there is no sanity checking for null here.

Answer (score 1):

TheGeneral's answer covers why you are getting caught out with lazy loading. You may also need to include Asset to get AssetName.

With AutoMapper you can avoid the need to Eager Load the entities by employing `.ProjectTo<T>()` to the `IQueryable`, provided there is a User accessible in Group.

For instance:

```
var roles = db.Groups.Where(g => g.User.Internetid == username)
   .SelectMany(g => g.Roles.Where(r => r.Asset.AssetName == application))
   .ProjectTo<RoleApi>()
   .ToList();
```

This should leverage the deferred execution where AutoMapper will effectively project in the `.Select()` needed to populate the RoleApi instance based on your mapping/inspection.

Comment: I would definitely take this path.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another way of avoiding lazy loading. You can also look at projection and have only those fields which you need rather than loading the entire columns.

```
var userRoles = Mapper.Map<List<RoleApi>>(
db.Users.Where(u => u.InternetId == username).Select(../* projection */ )
  .Groups.SelectMany(g => g.Roles.Where(r => r.Asset.AssetName == application)));
```

EF also comes with Include:

```
var userRoles = Mapper.Map<List<RoleApi>>(
db.Users.Where(u => u.InternetId == username).Select(../* projection */ )
  .Include(g => g.Roles.Where(r => r.Asset.AssetName == application)));
```

Then can iterate the collection using multiple for loops.

Answer (score 0):

You have to be aware of two differences:

- The difference between IEnumerable and IQueryable
- The difference between functions that return `IQueryable<TResult>` (lazy) and functions that return `TResult` (executing)

### Difference between `Enumerable` and `Queryable`

. A LINQ statement that is `AsEnumerable` is meant to be processed in your local process. It contains all code and all calls to execute the statement. This statement is executed as soon as `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` are called, either explicitly, or implicitly using `foreach` or LINQ statements that don't return `IEnumerable<...>`, like `ToList`, `FirstOrDefault`, and `Any`.

In contrast, an `IQueryable` is not meant to be processed in your process (however it can be done if you want). It is usually meant to be processed by a different process, usually a database management system.

For this an `IQueryable` holds an `Expression` and a `Provider`. The `Expression` represents the query that must be executed. The `Provider` knows who must execute the query (the DBMS), and which language this executor uses (usually SQL). When `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` are called, the `Provider` takes the `Expression` and translates it into the language of the `Executor`. The query is sen't to the executor. The returned data is presented `AsEnumerable`, where `GetEnumerator` and `MoveNext` are called.

Because of this translation into SQL, an IQueryable can't do all the things that an IEnumerable can do. The main thing is that it can't call your local functions. It can't even execute all LINQ functions. The better the quality of the `Provider` the more it can do. See [supported and unsupported LINQ methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/ef/language-reference/supported-and-unsupported-linq-methods-linq-to-entities)

### Lazy LINQ methods and executing LINQ methods

There are two groups of LINQ methods. Those that return `IQueryable<...>/IEnumerable<...> and those that do not.

The first group use lazy loading. This means that at the end of the LINQ statement the query has been created, but it is not executed yet. Only 'GetEnumerator`and`MoveNext`will make that the`Provider`will translate the`Expression` and order the DBMS to execute the query.

Concatenating `IQueryables` will only change the `Expression`. This is a fairly fast procedure. Hence there is no performance gain if you make one big LINQ expression instead of concatenate them before you execute the query.

Usually the DBMS is smarter and better prepared to do selections than your process. The transfer of selected data to your local process is one of the slower parts of your query.

> Advice: Try to create your LINQ statements such, that the executing
>   statement is the last one that can be executed by the DBMS. Make sure
>   that you only select the properties that you actually plan to use.

So for example, don't transfer foreign keys if you don't use them.

### Back to your question

Leaving the mapper out of the question you start with:

```
db.Users.SingleOrDefault(...)
```

SingleOrDefault is a non-lazy function. It doesn't return `IQueryable<...>`. It will execute the query. It will transport one complete `User` to your local process, including its `Roles`.

Advice postpone the SingleOrDefault to the last statement:

```
var result = myDbcontext.Users
    .Where(user => user.InternetId == username)
    .SelectMany(user => user.Groups.Roles.Where(role => role.Asset.AssetName == application))

     // until here, the query is not executed yet, execute it now:
     .SingleOrDefault();
```

In words: From the sequence of `Users`, keep only those `Users` with an `InternetId` that equals `userName`. From all remaining `Users` (which you hope to be only one), select the sequence of `Roles` of the `Groups` of each `User`. However, we don't want to select all `Roles`, we only keep the `Roles` with an `AssetName` equal to `application`. Now put all remaining `Roles` into one collection (the `many` part in `SelectMany`), and select the zero or one remaining `Role` that you expect.